# Displaying table with data and controls

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad

I'm new to iOS development. I would like to know if there is any control or API to display data and controls in tabular format.

Example:

- column 1 -- checkbox
- Column 2 -- string
- Column 3 -- dropdown with sub   categories.
- column 4 -- dropdown with actionable items, means selecting/changing should raise an event.

And sorting based on specific column data when user touches column header.

We developed this in WPF for a desktop application and everything was written in XAML. Now we want to do something similar in iOS app, and android but we would like to start with iOS app.

1. Is it good to have native app for this requirement? or
   HWC/browser based app?
2. Is there any 3rd party library(paid or
   free) available?

sample image link, for better text clarity:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/qf2aj.png

[image: Sample image]

Comment: Add an image about your column please

Comment: @rplusg please let me know if my answer was helpful, or if I need to elaborate on it. I understand what you're trying to accomplish, and hope my advise is useful.

Answer (score 4):

Your question has a few parts, so I'll break it down:

For multicolumn tabular data look at [ShinobiGrids](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/ios/shinobigrids). You'll be able to have as many columns as you'd like.

Regarding your examples thought;

- Checkboxes aren't an iOS concept. UISwitch is.
- yes! strings are pretty easy! and they'll work with Shinobi.
- you'll want to reconsider this point. UIPickerViews are not going to realistically fit in a grid cell. I cannot elaborate on how I'd solve this, unfortunately.

I've never implemented sorting in Shinobi, but I'm fairly certain I've seen the APIs there.

**Edit:**

Here is [an article](http://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2012/05/23/extending-shinobigrids-with-sorting/) talking about sorting a ShinobiGrid.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can achieve it by custom tableviewCell

**instantiate three different nib for UItableViewCell**

for drop down with subcategory you should use expandableList,Here's [a link](http://www.example.com/)!.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to use hybrid app (such as PhoneGap) and not native. Your Excel like arrays are really far from Apple Interface Guidelines.

For your other questions, I won't answer cause it's out of the rules of Stackoverflow (you can't ask people to advise you a software/api/library more than another, it's subjective and your topic could be close because of it.)

If you want to do it in native environment, consider about thinking again your UI and do not translate from an existing UI (moreover desktop UI) to something different.

Hope this helps !

Comment: If it's against the HIG, using PhoneGap doesn't magically make it better.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely native app development is a good choice for your application development. for iOS development check the below links :

•[Link 1](http://maniacdev.com/2013/07/open-source-ios-ui-controll-allowing-you-to-create-flat-ios-7-style-uitableview-accessory-views)
•[Link 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2)
•[Link 3](http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/)
•[Link 4](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/customizing-uitableview-cell/)

Answer (score -1):

Just create the custom UItableviewcell class and load the same inside the UItableView delegate method cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Answer (score -1):

`UICollectionView` is aimed at grids with the same cell style for each, but since it provides a data source which allows customizing each cell (albeit loaded from the same nib) you might be able to use it for your needs.

I'd try that out before deciding on custom classes.